# Not receiving crash reports in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

#### Describe your environment

- Xcode version: 11.2.1
- Firebase SDK version: 6.16.0
- Firebase Component: Crashlytics (Auth, Core, Database, Firestore, Messaging, Storage, etc)
- Component version: 4.0.0-beta3
- Installation method: `CocoaPods`

#### Describe the problem

After upgrading to the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK, we are not receiving crash reports for either debug or release builds. We verified the installation & correct usage of the GoogleService-Info.plist. When forcing a crash locally using `fatalError`, on the next execution `Crashlytics.crashlytics().didCrashDuringPreviousExecution()` always returns `false`.

Steps to reproduce:

Force a simple crash using `fatalError`

Relevant Code:

in `didFinishLaunching`

```
print(Crashlytics.crashlytics().didCrashDuringPreviousExecution())
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 35) {
   fatalError()
 }
```

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4798

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support directly for assistance. Stack Overflow isn't really a good place to troubleshoot Firebase SDKs and console data that doesn't appear as you expect.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Did you send the correct DYSM files to Firebase? There's a new way to do that with a bundle script instead of exporting it from iTunesConnect.